# Is ShowcaseView library free to use?

Tags: java, android, google-play, showcaseview

I am using ShowcaseLibrary in my android app,i.e.
https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView
If I am uploading tha app on playstore then what should I have to do?
I haven't uploaded any app on play store,so I don't know.
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its free to use. Read more about [Apache Licence 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

Comment: Is it allowed to use in Google Play? I mean, does it comply with all the many Google policies? Will my users be safe when using external libraries I don't even know who developed it.